# CSS - Different Styles depending on different domains

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, stylesheet

I will change the style from sites depending on domains.

Firefox-Example:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("http//www.example.com") {
    body {
        background-color: rgb(176,230,230);     
    }         
}
```

Is there something similar, which works for Internet Explorer and Chrome?

Regards

Comment: use @-webkit-document for chrome

Comment: Do you have an example?
Or is it just @-webkit-document url-prefix("http//www.example.com")...because this wont work

Comment: @Stefan1988 check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nathansmith/880619) - note the two commented links.

Comment: Have solved it with a JavaScript Function, because i didn´t found any suitable solution for IE/Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can try URL based CSS files.

If you are using RoR, something like this would work. I am sure other frameworks will have something similar too.

```
- if (request.host == "http//www.example.com")
  = stylesheet_link_tag    "example", media: "all"
- else
  = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
```

Comment: No, i don´t use RoR, and if it´s possible, i don´t want several css files